# How do guests tell each other apart from the hosts?

Tags: westworld-2016

How do guests tell each other apart from the hosts?

In Westworld, there are many guests.  How do they only kill the robots?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63507/in-westworld-how-can-guests-tell-the-difference-between-guests-and-hosts

Answer (score 2):

The answer is easy tho. Just ask them a question about the world out side of the park. A host wouldn’t say anything back, because they’re programmed to not pay attention to stuff like that. When a guest would more then likely have something to say on the matter.    Hope that helped

Comment: While the question may be a bit unclear, the answer area is for answers, not comments on questions. Once you have 50 reputation, you’ll be able to comment anywhere.

Comment: that's why i amended what i posted. to put a proper answer in.   :P

Answer (score 2):

William's friend, Logan, at one point explains the easiest and fastest way to find out if someone is a human or a Host, when William asks the same question:  Shoot them.

Westworld weapons don't work on humans.